# How to align a menu in NavigationProvider?

Tags: c#, menu, navigation, aspnetboilerplate

Good day.

I'm using MVC Core ASP.NET Boilerplate v0.9.6.

I'm trying to align a side menu to look like this:

- Item 1
- Item 2

  - Item 2.1

    - Item 2.1.1
- Item 3

This is how the current code is displaying the menu:

- Item 1
- Item 2

  - Item 2.1
  - Item 2.1.1
- Item 3

Here is the code:

```
// Menu for CRM Module
        .AddItem(
                new MenuItemDefinition(
                    "CRMModule",
                    L("CRMModule"),
                    url: "CRMModule",
                    icon: "fa fa-wrench",
                    requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_SparesRequirements
                        ).AddItem(
                            new MenuItemDefinition(
                                "Companies",
                                L("Companies"),
                                url: "Company",
                                icon: "fa fa-building",
                                requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Companies
                                            )

                        ).AddItem(
                             new MenuItemDefinition(
                                "Quotations",
                                L("Quotations"),
                                url: "Quotation",
                                icon: "fa fa-list-alt",
                                requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
                                ).AddItem(
                                         new MenuItemDefinition(
                                         "Quotations",
                                         L("List"),
                                         url: "Quotation",
                                         icon: "fa fa-table",
                                         requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
                                         )
                                ).AddItem(
                                        new MenuItemDefinition(
                                        "Quotations",
                                        L("Create"),
                                        url: "Quotation/CreateQuote",
                                        icon: "fa fa-plus",
                                        requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
                                        )
                                )

                        ).AddItem(
                            new MenuItemDefinition(
                                "Leads",
                                L("Leads"),
                                url: "Lead",
                                icon: "fa fa-building-o",
                                requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Leads
                               )
                       )
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this is what you want:

- CRMModule

  - Companies
  - Quotations

    - List

      - Create
  - Leads

Firstly, each `MenuItemDefinition` should have an unique `Name` (the first parameter).

Secondly, it becomes obvious what you need to do when you use proper indentation.

**Before**:

```
).AddItem(
    new MenuItemDefinition(
        "Quotations", // "List"
        L("List"),
        url: "Quotation",
        icon: "fa fa-table",
        requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
    ) // Remove
).AddItem(
    new MenuItemDefinition(
        "Quotations", // "Create"
        L("Create"),
        url: "Quotation/CreateQuote",
        icon: "fa fa-plus",
        requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
    )
)
```

**After**:

```
).AddItem(
    new MenuItemDefinition(
        "List",
        L("List"),
        url: "Quotation",
        icon: "fa fa-table",
        requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
    ).AddItem(                                                       // Indented
        new MenuItemDefinition(                                      // Indented
            "Create",                                                // Indented
            L("Create"),                                             // Indented
            url: "Quotation/CreateQuote",                            // Indented
            icon: "fa fa-plus",                                      // Indented
            requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations // Indented
        ) // Added
    )
)
```

---

## SideBarNav/Default.cshtml

To support 3rd level menu items, change [these lines](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/b5c18c989fa236d768d3ec6662edb5d66b4612c3/aspnet-core/src/AbpCompanyName.AbpProjectName.Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/Components/SideBarNav/Default.cshtml#L72-L74):

```
<a href="@calculateMenuUrl(subSubMenuItem.Url)">
    @subSubMenuItem.DisplayName
</a>
```

to:

```
@if (subSubMenuItem.Items.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    <a href="@calculateMenuUrl(subSubMenuItem.Url)">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subSubMenuItem.Icon))
        {
            <i class="material-icons">@subSubMenuItem.Icon</i>
        }
        <span>@subSubMenuItem.DisplayName</span>
    </a>
}
else
{
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(subSubMenuItem.Icon))
        {
            <i class="material-icons">@subSubMenuItem.Icon</i>
        }
        <span>@subSubMenuItem.DisplayName</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="ml-menu">
        @foreach (var subsubSubMenuItem in subSubMenuItem.Items)
        {
            <li class="@(Model.ActiveMenuItemName == subsubSubMenuItem.Name ? "active" : "")">
                <a href="@calculateMenuUrl(subsubSubMenuItem.Url)">
                    @subsubSubMenuItem.DisplayName
                </a>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Create` sub-menu is the one you want to make go down one level, so it will be defined under the `List` item:

```
new MenuItemDefinition(
"List", // so it will be defined under "List"
L("Create"),
url: "Quotation/CreateQuote",
icon: "fa fa-plus",
requiredPermissionName: PermissionNames.Pages_Quotations
)
```